# Git commit on GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need to know that what if I create a repository on my device and keep making continuous commits to it. For example, I created and finished a repository and made about 50 commits, but I haven't pushed it to GitHub yet, not even once. So if I push the repository after completing it, will the 50 commits show up on GitHub too?

Comment: Have you tried? :) One command to test it out, I promise.

Comment: I tried after I made sure that my commits won't be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you commit 50 times to your local git repo, you are essentially appending to the database.
When you push your local repo to github, the entire local database is "copied" to github, including the 50 commits.

so the answer to your question is: yes, github will have a record of the 50 commits you made to your local repo.

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely yes. That's something we like on git.